# Проблемы со Scanner в Java

Tags: java, scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
~~~~~~~~~
int coordA, coordB;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
                System.out.println("Enter the coordinates: ");
                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    coordA = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
                    continue;
                }
                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    coordB = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
                    continue;
                }
                if (board[coordA][coordB] == 'X' || board[coordA][coordB] == 'O') {
                    System.out.println("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!");
                    continue;
                }
                if (coordA > 3 || coordB > 3 || coordA <= 0 || coordB <= 0){
                    System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
                }
            }
```

Допустим на первой итерации вы ввели буквы. Тогда, при переходе ко второй итерации scanner не считывает ввод

```
You should enter numbers!
Enter the coordinates: 
You should enter numbers!
Enter the coordinates:
```

openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-suse-1.1-x8664)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-suse-1.1-x8664, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hasNextInt обрабатывает(как и nextLine) /n, символ конца строки, из System.out.println прошлой итерации цикла.

Так что, нужно просто добавить scanner.nextLine(); после вывода строки

```java
while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Enter the coordinates: ");
                    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                        coordA = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                        coordB = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (board[coordA][coordB] == 'X' || board[coordA][coordB] == 'O') {
                        System.out.println("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (coordA > 3 || coordB > 3){
                        System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        continue;
                    }
```